# Auto Calculate Input Fields

Tags: react-admin

Please could someone help answer this:

I have 2 NumberInput controls, one input and the other is disabled. I need to input number in the first input field, the disabled field to show this number/100. The two NumberInput will have source fields that will save to the current record in the simpleform.

How do I do this in react-admin

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a shorter solution to this question:
All I did was to do the calculation within *FormDataConsumer*. Now, I am able to get the calculated value and it updates the correct record in the array.

Thanks

```
<FormDataConsumer>
  {({
    formData, // The whole form data
    scopedFormData, // The data for this item of the ArrayInput
    getSource, // A function to get the valid source inside an ArrayInput
    ...rest
  }) => {
    if (typeof scopedFormData !== 'undefined') {
      scopedFormData.total = scopedFormData.quantity * scopedFormData.unitprice;
      return (
        <NumberInput disabled defaultValue={scopedFormData.total} label="Total" source={getSource('total')} />
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <NumberInput disabled label="Total" source={getSource('total')} />
      )
    }            
  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use the method described in the docs under section [Linking two inputs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs)

In essence: You can create your own input component where you can access the form values via the hook `useFormState`. Then just assign the desired value transformed the way you want e.g. divided by 100.

**Edit**

Found one more even cleaner way - using the [final-form-calculate](https://github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate) to create a decorator and pass it to the `<FormWithRedirect />` component like so:

```
import createDecorator from 'final-form-calculate'

const calculator = createDecorator(
  // Calculations:
{
   field: 'number1', // when the value of foo changes...
   updates: {
     number2: (fooValue, allValues) => allValues["number1"] * 2
   }
})

...

<FormWithRedirect
   ...
   decorators={[calculator]}
/>
```

Check out this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq52p6v96y?file=/index.js:1744-1770)

Answer (score 0):

### Using FormDataConsumer

```
<FormDataConsumer>
  {({ formData }) => (
    <NumberInput defaultValue={formData.my_first_input / 100} source="second_input"/>
  )}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

### Using the useFormState hook

```
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form';

...

const { values: { my_first_input }} = useFormState({ subscription: { values: true } });

...

<NumberInput defaultValue={my_first_input / 100} source="second_input"/>
```

Source: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

### Dynamic

You need to use the `useForm` hook of **react-final-form** to make your input dynamic:

```
import { useForm, useFormState } from 'react-final-form';

...

const {change} = useForm();
const { values: { my_first_input }} = useFormState({ subscription: { values: true } });


useEffect(() => {
  change('my_second_input', my_first_input / 100);
}, [change, my_first_input]);

...


<NumberInput defaultValue={my_first_input / 100} source="second_input"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Striped and Kia Kaha for your efforts. I have tried the *FormDataConsumer*, it does what I want except that the result in the second_input only gets result the first time I input value in first_input. I think the reason for this is the defaultValue property used. What other property can I use in the second_input that will show result anytime I enter value in the first_input. Thanks

Comment: You welcome :) I've updated my comment, try with the `useForm` hook.

Comment: Hi Striped, thanks once again. I got this error *Error: useForm must be used inside of a <Form> component*. I am actually using SimpleForm- I am not using custom form. Also what is the best way to get the form field because I am using the arrayinput record(salesoutdet). From the json below, total should be computed from unitprice and quantity                                                                                                    {
 "salesdate": "2020-11-23",
  "distributorid": 1,
  "salesrep": 4,
  "salesoutdet": [
 {
   "unitprice": 10,
   "quantity": 5,
   "total": 50}]}

Comment: You did good. But as `useForm` needs to be called **inside** a Form, you need to split  you component in two, once with the `SimpleForm` and a second with its child where you can actually call `useForm` because it is **wrapped** in the `SimpleForm`.

Comment: Or you just create your own Input wrapping you `NumberInput` like describe here https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component. This could also allow you to use both `useForm` and `useFormState` hooks.

Comment: Hi Striped. I am new to React-Admin. I will try and let you know. In the meantime, where will the *useEffect* be when I have moved others around? Thanks

Comment: It will be where you are allow to call the `useForm` hook too, so in your child wrapper or you custom input wrapper I guess.

Comment: Hi Striped. Thanks so much. I eventually got it working. You are a star!

Comment: Thanks, glad to help :) do not forget to mark the answer as the accepted one if you consider that's the good one.

Comment: Hi Striped.Thx 4 ystdy.There is a little issue to resolve b4 I certify this post correct.It works well when d inputs are on the header of my json.When d inputs are on the detail, it updates d 1st record of the details.For example: see this json below: i need to find the total on each of *salesoutdet*.It only works on d 1st record,it fails 4 d 2nd                                                                                       {
  "id":1
  "salesoutdet": [
 {
   "unitprice": 10,
   "quantity": 5,
   "total": 50
 },
 {
   "unitprice": 2,
   "quantity": 1,
   "total": 2
 }
 ]
}

Comment: I think d problem is how to tell the useFormState what record of the array being passed to work with: see my *FormDataConsumer*: The TotalField is enclosed in the DataConsumer                                                                       <FormDataConsumer>
              {({
                formData,
                scopedFormData,                getSource,                ...rest
              }) => {
           
                return scopedFormData ? <TotalField source={getSource('total')} {...rest}/> : null;
              }}
            </FormDataConsumer>

Comment: This is another issue related to the use of an `<ArrayInput>` and `SimpleFornIterator`. I will let you search this way.

Comment: Hi Striped. Pls do you have an idea. I have searched..no one seems to have either asked the question or know how to resolve this. I think what I need to know is how to get the actual record number of the array I am working with at the moment. If I can get that, I will be able to pass it to the useFormState to update the actual total

Comment: It depends mainly on how you have implemented it. As I said this is a new issue that you can ask on SO. I can't help you with so few information.

Comment: Hi Strped, I have resolved the issue I was having. I did it another way without using the useForm hooks. See my answer above. Thanks

Comment: Good job! Congrat :)