# React Admin - how can I autofill (update) field values on change

Tags: react-admin

I have a Google places autocomplete input and need to populate address related fields based on selected place as below:

```
  <GPAutocompleteInput
    source="address_full"
    placeholder="Find address"
    onPlaceSelected={onPlaceSelected}
    gaOptions={{ types: ["address"] }}
  />

  <TextInput source="address_street" disabled label="Ulica" />
  <TextInput source="address_postcode" disabled label="Kod pocztowy" />
  <TextInput source="address_city" disabled label="Miasto" />
```

Now I would like the 3 disabled inputs to be filled in with the address components from the selected place but can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried providing initialValues to the SimpleForm component and this works ok in the create view but not in the edit because those fields already have a value the values are not being updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto Calculate Input Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64811031/auto-calculate-input-fields)

Answer (score -1):

react-final-form provides a simple hook allowing me to change values

```
import { useForm } from "react-final-form";

const form = useForm();
form.change("address_city", components?.address_city);
```

There may be a better way as this requires building a custom component to use form context required by the hook.